# Сдвиг мобильной версии на айфонах <iphone 6. laravel

Tags: html, bootstrap, laravel

iphone 5
[image: ipone5]
iphone 4
[image: iphone4]
iphone 6
[image: iphone6]

Абсолютно на всех андроидах и в панели разработчика гугл по всем экранам все отлично. Но на айфонах меньше 6 идет перекос, разрабатываю на laravel использую bootstrap. Пробовал использовать [Автопрефикс](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/laravel-mix-and-autoprefixer), но эффекта не получил.

```
 <header class="container-fluid p-0 mr-lg-6 ml-lg-6 ml-0 mr-0 mt-1 row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center header">
<div class="flex-lg-row flex-column d-flex container header-body">
    <div class="col-5 header-logo d-block">
        @if($settings->domain_name !== 'index')<a class="d-block" href="http://podrabotka.pw">
            <img class="header-logo-img d-block" src="{{ asset('img/logo.png') }}"></a>
        @else <img class="header-logo-img d-block" src="{{ asset('img/logo.png') }}">
        @endif
    </div>
    @if (($settings->domain_name !== 'anketa')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'rezume')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'info'))
        <div class="header-cont text-right col-7 d-none d-lg-block">
            <p class="header-tit">Онлайн консультация</p>
            <p class="header-phone d-flex align-items-start justify-content-end mt-1 mb-0">+7(921)121-79-19</p>
            @if ( ($settings->domain_name !== 'kassir')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'kassir-vd')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'rabotnik')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'rtz')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'gryzchik')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'promoyter')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'oficiant')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'raznorabochiy')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'predstavitel')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'recruiter'))
                <button class="btn btn-link header-choose cursor-hand" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" id="#foo">
                    г. {{ $settings->city }}
                </button>
                <span>{{ $settings->address }}</span>
                <a href="#oformlenie" class="ml-1">Схема проезда</a>
            @endif
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
@if (($settings->domain_name !== 'anketa')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'rezume')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'info'))
    <div class="container d-none d-lg-block">
        <nav class="main-nav menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-default d-flex justify-content-between flex-row header-nav">
                <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
                    @if ( ($settings->domain_name !== 'kassir')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'kassir-vd')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'rabotnik')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'rtz')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'gryzchik')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'promoyter')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'oficiant')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'raznorabochiy')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'predstavitel')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'recruiter'))
                        <a class="nav-link text-center pb-3" href="#vakancii">Вакансии</a>
                    @else <a class="nav-link text-center pb-3" href="#bez">Обьекты</a>
                    @endif
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
                    <a class="nav-link text-center pb-3" href="#rabota">Преимущества</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
                    @if ( ($settings->domain_name !== 'kassir')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'kassir-vd')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'rabotnik')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'rtz')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'gryzchik')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'promoyter')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'oficiant')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'raznorabochiy')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'predstavitel')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'recruiter'))
                        <a class="nav-link text-center pb-3" href="#student">Отзывы</a>
                    @else <a class="nav-link text-center pb-3" href="#oplata">О вакансии</a>
                    @endif
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
                    @if ( ($settings->domain_name !== 'kassir')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'kassir-vd')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'rabotnik')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'rtz')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'gryzchik')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'promoyter')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'oficiant')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'raznorabochiy')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'predstavitel')&&($settings->domain_name !== 'recruiter'))
                        <a class="nav-link text-center pb-3" href="#oplata">О компании</a>
                    @else <a class="nav-link text-center pb-3" href="#oformlenie">Контакты</a>
                    @endif
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
                    <a class="nav-link text-center pb-3" href="#grafik">Заполнить анкету</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Картинки не открываются почему-то.

Comment: Перезалил, теперь видно?

Comment: Похоже на то, что используется `css`, который не поддерживается старыми айфонами. Нужно выложить соответствующий `css`. Или сделать пример, воспроизводящий проблему. Например, на старых айфонах не поддерживается `flexbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, разобрался, проблема решилась после исправления на скриншоте. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте описание текстом в ответ, чтобы потом другие могли найти его. Поисковики не индексируют текст на картинках.